# AsyncTask in Android onCreate method needs to run twice and update accordingly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, oncreate

So I don't have a very good understanding of how AsyncTasks work, so that may be why my current code isn't working. If I have an AsyncTask running in my onCreate method as such:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new UpdateSpinnerTask().execute(MainActivity.DUMMY_URI);
  }
```

and then it runs properly. Then if I click a button to go to a different activity (ListView), basically what I had been doing was restarting MainActivity so that my view would be recreated. Now the spinner task then doesn't work properly afterwards. Like it doesn't do what it's supposed to do in post execute.

It generically looks like:

```
    private class UpdateSpinnerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... url) {
            }
    }
```

So my question is if I want to run the stuff in AsyncTask multiple times in my onCreate, is that possible?

Comment: What exactly happened the 2nd time you started your MainActivity - did `doInBackground()` get called, did `onPostExecute()` get called? Yes, you can run your AsyncTask multiple times but what exactly did you fail to achieve the second time e.g. modifying some view?

Comment: my bad guys. It was a stupid error with my if statement. It was running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `UpdateSpinnerTask` run again when go back from another Activity? Well, you should move the `UpdateSpinnerTask` calling code from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`. Since `onCreate()` is not called every time when go into your Activity. You should known more about [Activity's lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: Whenever I go back to this Activity, I restart it so that's not the issue. thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about running `AsyncTask` twice in `onCreate()`. This is about spawning 2 separate background threads (it does not make a lot of sense to re-use the same AsyncTask object) in 2 activity life-cycles.

If you have trouble calling `execute()` the second time, try `executeOnExecutor()` (note that you can only do this for API 11 and above)

Also, if you can clarify your question (see my comment), perhaps I can give a better answer